# Dificuldade em Posicionar Background image

Tags: html

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]Senhores(as), estou tentando posicionar uma imagem ao fundo do meu projeto, mas ao utilizar o cover o mesmo corta a parte de baixo, e quanto eu utilizo qualquer outra  forma ele replica a imagem e 4 quadrados, conforme anexo abaixo, poderiam me dar uma luz de como ajustar esse problema ?

```css
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.jumbo {
 background-image: url(../Images/metaVendedores.png");
 background-size: cover;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.box {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.p1, .p2, .p3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.p1 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.p2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.p3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.p2::after {
  content: "texto";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="box">

      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN1.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN1.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN1.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN2.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN2.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN2.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN3.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN3.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN3.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN4.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN4.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN4.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN5.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN5.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN5.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[![Imagem Cortando[![][1]][2]][2]][3]

Comment: Gabriel sobre a imagem repetir 4x, basta vc colocar background-repeat: no-repeat; que resolver. Mas sobre encaixar a imagem no conteiner vc tem que usar as propriedades do background-size, aqui tem um link uqe vai te ajudar a entender como funciona https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Comment: Vc tb pode tentar ajusta como o background-position para ficar melhor o alinhamento, o ideal e usar junto com o bg-size no seu caso. Aqui tem um link pra te ajudar tb https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: @hugocsl, vou verificar essas documentações, obrigado. Referente a imagem, mesmo adicionando o no-repeat, ela não repete, e fica somente em um dos quadrados, conforme imagem acima que acabei de adicionar.

Comment: Aqu tem a documentação sobre o Repeat, da uma olhada se vc não deixou passar nada no seu código: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
.jumbo{  
  background-image: url(../Images/metaVendedores.png");  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  <--não repete a imagem
  background-position: 0% 0%; <-- Posição da imagem
  background-size: 100% 100%; <--tamanho da imagem
}
```

pode tentar dessa forma também:

```
.jumbo{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url(../Images/metaVendedores.png") no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
}
```

Abaixo segue um snippet com seu código alterado:

```css
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.jumbo{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg2MS.png') no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
.box {
  width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 1.5em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
.p1, .p2, .p3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.p1 {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.p2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.p3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.p2::after {
  content: "texto";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbo">

  <div class="container">

    <div class="box">

      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN1.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN1.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN1.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN2.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN2.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN2.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN3.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN3.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN3.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN4.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN4.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN4.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
      <div class="p1">
        <c:out value="${VN5.rows[0].FUNCIONARIO}" />
      </div>
      <div class="p2">
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${VN5.rows[0].META}" type="currency" />
      </div>
      <div class="p3">
        <c:out value="${VN5.rows[0].ACUMULADO}" />
  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```